# Mysql pagination without offset

Tags: mysql, pagination

Let's assume I have got a table with these data:

[image: Table data]

I want to order it by createdAt column DESC, and id column DESC

```
select id, createdAt from post order by createdAt desc, id desc
```

Now it looks like this:

[image: ORDER BY createdAt DESC, id DESC]

I want to paginate it with 2 items per page and don't want to use `offset`, just `limit`:

```
select id, createdAt from post order by createdAt desc, id desc limit 2
```

[image]

To get the next 2 items i use this query:

```
SELECT id, createdAt FROM post  WHERE createdAt <= '2014-11-16 09:11:03' AND (id < '15' OR createdAt < '2014-11-16 09:11:03') ORDER BY createdAt DESC, id DESC LIMIT 2
```

[image]

I can go on like this. Get the last item's `createdAt` and `id` then use it for `next` page query.

But i'm trying to formulate the `previous page` query for almost two days and can't figure out a way yet.

Here is what i tried already:

Get the first item from current result (instead of last) use it's `id` and `createdAt` field and reverse the conditions in query (`createdAt >=, id >, created at >`). But this query always gives me the first two results (which is normal because the rows providing this conditions are the first two).

I'm already out of ideas. I need help. Thanks.

Comment: Any reason for avoiding offset?

Comment: @Mihai this table will fill out pretty quick (it's for some analytics, log data) and offset will slow it down after a couple of pages. More info: https://i.imgur.com/Q8ZRKPs.jpg and http://www.slideshare.net/Eweaver/efficient-pagination-using-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
mysql> #select all in reverse
mysql> select id, createdAt from post order by createdAt desc, id desc;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | createdAt           |
+------+---------------------+
|   16 | 2014-11-16 09:11:18 |
|   15 | 2014-11-16 09:11:03 |
|   14 | 2014-11-16 09:10:32 |
|   13 | 2014-11-16 09:10:05 |
|   12 | 2014-11-16 09:09:47 |
|   11 | 2014-11-13 18:35:01 |
|   10 | 2014-11-13 18:33:08 |
|    9 | 2014-11-13 18:33:01 |
|    8 | 2014-11-13 17:51:21 |
|    7 | 2014-11-13 17:40:30 |
|    6 | 2014-11-12 18:37:44 |
|    5 | 2014-11-12 18:21:44 |
|    4 | 2014-11-12 18:17:30 |
|    3 | 2014-11-12 17:31:31 |
|    2 | 2014-11-11 18:37:40 |
|    1 | 2014-11-11 17:28:41 |
+------+---------------------+
16 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> #select last two
mysql> select id, createdAt from post order by createdAt desc, id desc limit 2;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | createdAt           |
+------+---------------------+
|   16 | 2014-11-16 09:11:18 |
|   15 | 2014-11-16 09:11:03 |
+------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> #select next button
mysql> SELECT id, createdAt FROM post  WHERE createdAt <= '2014-11-16 09:11:03' AND (id < '15' OR createdAt < '2014-11-16 09:11:03') ORDER BY createdAt DESC, id DESC LIMIT 2;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | createdAt           |
+------+---------------------+
|   14 | 2014-11-16 09:10:32 |
|   13 | 2014-11-16 09:10:05 |
+------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> #select next button again
mysql> SELECT id, createdAt FROM post  WHERE createdAt <= '2014-11-16 09:10:05' AND (id < '13' OR createdAt < '2014-11-16 09:10:05') ORDER BY createdAt DESC, id DESC LIMIT 2;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | createdAt           |
+------+---------------------+
|   12 | 2014-11-16 09:09:47 |
|   11 | 2014-11-13 18:35:01 |
+------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> #undo next button (just to get back conceptually)
mysql> SELECT id, createdAt FROM post  WHERE createdAt <= '2014-11-16 09:11:03' AND (id < '15' OR createdAt < '2014-11-16 09:11:03') ORDER BY createdAt DESC, id DESC LIMIT 2;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | createdAt           |
+------+---------------------+
|   14 | 2014-11-16 09:10:32 |
|   13 | 2014-11-16 09:10:05 |
+------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> #we already saw 'next' from here
mysql> #now let's click the previous button
mysql> #change the direction of the inequalities and order by statement
mysql> SELECT id, createdAt FROM post  WHERE createdAt >= '2014-11-16 09:10:32' AND (id > 14 OR createdAt > '2014-11-16 09:10:32') ORDER BY createdAt asc, id asc LIMIT 2;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | createdAt           |
+------+---------------------+
|   15 | 2014-11-16 09:11:03 |
|   16 | 2014-11-16 09:11:18 |
+------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> #and if you want them sorted in desc:
mysql> select id, createdAt from (SELECT id, createdAt FROM post  WHERE createdAt >= '2014-11-16 09:10:32' AND (id > 14 OR createdAt > '2014-11-16 09:10:32') ORDER BY createdAt asc, id asc LIMIT 2 ) a order by createdAt desc, id desc;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | createdAt           |
+------+---------------------+
|   16 | 2014-11-16 09:11:18 |
|   15 | 2014-11-16 09:11:03 |
+------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```